# How to get all control list of the Form in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get all controls of win form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735190/how-to-get-all-controls-of-win-form)

i have a winform like below in picture.
[image]
and i want a list of all the controls of the MainForm.
Like this:
MainForm
Button1
Panel1
TextBox1
Panel2
Button2
TextBox2

Comment: Just loop through the controls that exist on the MainForm, Panel1, and Panel2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work (not perfect code by any means...just meant to get the idea across):

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetSelfAndChildrenRecursive(Control parent)
{
    List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();

    foreach(Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        controls.AddRange(GetSelfAndChildrenRecursive(child));
    }

    controls.Add(parent);

    return controls;
}

var result = GetSelfAndChildrenRecursive(topLevelControl)
```

Comment: parent control should gobefore children?

Comment: mhm shouldn't be really important here :)

Comment: just a suggestion :) already gave +1