# Windows Forms - method for iterating all MDIparent's buttons is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

So it's obviously something simple but I'm losing too much time on this topic already.
I have a very simple(as it should be in my opinion) method which task is to iterate through all buttons in my parent form.

Here it is:

```
public void SetForeColor(BaseForm frm, Form f)
{
    foreach (ToolStripButton button in frm.Controls.OfType<ToolStripButton>())
    {               
            MessageBox.Show("Soles clicked"+" "+f.Name.ToString());
    }

}
```

Where `BaseForm frm` is the argument that should take the `MDIparent` as value. I call this method from another one where I actually get the `MDIparent` :

```
 protected void LoadForm<T>(ToolStripButton formButton, string buttonText) where T : Form
        {
            MainForm frm = this.MdiParent as MainForm;
            if (frm == null) frm = this as MainForm;
            T sendTo;
....
            SetForeColor(frm, sendTo);
```

But I don't get any response. The `LoadForm<T>` function is working fine, so my suggestion is that I'm making mistake in the `foreach` but it seems so very straight forward to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ToolStripButton` is the standard button in the .net framework, your `foreach` loop will not execute as there will be no buttons of type `ToolStripButton` in the form's control collection.

ToolStripButtons have to be parented by a MenuStrip, ToolStrip or StatusStrip, so you would need to iterate any toolstrip's controls:

```
foreach (var strip in frm.Controls.OfType<ToolStrip>())
{
     foreach (var item in strip.Items)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Soles clicked " + f.Name.ToString());
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, easy and doing exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your buttons are not direct children of the form, but are contained in a [ToolStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.aspx) component that is itself a child of the form.

Try something like:

```
foreach (ToolStrip toolStrip in frm.Controls.OfType<ToolStrip>()) {
    foreach (ToolStripButton button
             in toolStrip.Controls.OfType<ToolStripButton>()) {               
        MessageBox.Show("Soles clicked " + f.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the form is of the same type too:

```
foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
    {
        if (frm.GetType() == form.GetType() 
            && frm != form)
        {
            frm.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach statement only searches the top layer of the controls collection.

```
foreach (ToolStripButton button in frm.Controls.OfType<ToolStripButton>()) {               
    MessageBox.Show("Soles clicked"+" "+f.Name.ToString());
}
```

While it is in fact a collection in a collection in a collection... etc. You need to search through the control collection and all its descendants.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735190/how-to-get-all-controls-of-win-form) has a method to retrieve all descendants.