# C# How to loop through all TextBox controls within an instance of user defined class?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user defined class:

```
public class UserDefined
{
   public winForm svdWinForm;
   .....
}
```

In other place, in an instance objUserDefined of UserDefined class

```
{
    ...
    objUserDefined.svdWinForm=anotherWinform;
    ...
    this.Close();
}
```

How to find the TextBox Controls of svdWinForm within objUserDefined , an instance of winForm?

I used follows. But it is unsuccessful.

```
foreach (Control x in objUserDefined.svdWinForm.Controls)
{
     if (x is TextBox)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Find a TextBox control!!");
        }
}
```

For instance to my question, I want to loop through textbox or other controls and set two objects equal as as following. My question is how to simplify the codes with foreach loops.

```
/// <summary>
/// Copy a CylinderDimension form to another form
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tgCylinderDimensionsWin">Target form</param>
/// <param name="srCylinderDimensionsWin">Source form</param>
public CopyCylinderDimensionsWin(CylinderDimensionsWin tgCylinderDimensionsWin, CylinderDimensionsWin srCylinderDimensionsWin)
{
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.rdInnerDiameter.Checked = srCylinderDimensionsWin.rdInnerDiameter.Checked;
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.rdOuterDiameter.Checked = srCylinderDimensionsWin.rdOuterDiameter.Checked;
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.txtShellDiameter.Text = srCylinderDimensionsWin.txtShellDiameter.Text;
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.txtShellLength.Text = srCylinderDimensionsWin.txtShellLength.Text;
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.txtShellThickness.Text = srCylinderDimensionsWin.txtShellThickness.Text;
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.txtNumberAdd.Text = srCylinderDimensionsWin.txtNumberAdd.Text;
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.chTrialLength.Checked = srCylinderDimensionsWin.chTrialLength.Checked;
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.txtTrialLength.Text = srCylinderDimensionsWin.txtTrialLength.Text;
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.chExempt.Checked = srCylinderDimensionsWin.chExempt.Checked;
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.txtTrialLength.Visible = srCylinderDimensionsWin.txtTrialLength.Visible;
    tgCylinderDimensionsWin.lbTrialLength.Visible = srCylinderDimensionsWin.lbTrialLength.Visible;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: SLate, the problem is there is no control found from objUserDefined.svdWinForm. Actually, there are 4 TextBox controls on the svdWinForm, an instance of winForm class embedded in UserDefined class.

Comment: They're probably in other panels.

Comment: you can search for something like "all winform controls" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735190/how-do-i-get-all-controls-of-a-form-in-windows-forms

Comment: The problem is that winForm is embedded in an userDefined class. objUserDefined is an instance of the userDifined class NOT an stance of winForm. The Controls of winForm (svdWinForm) embedded in the userDefined class cannot be found. It is weird!

Comment: User the form's Controls.Find() method.  It will properly recurse through the containers on the form.  And lowers the considerable risk of finding the wrong control.

Comment: does winForm class inherit System.Windows.Forms.Form class?

Comment: Yes. the winForm embedded in UserDefined class inherited System.Windows.Forms.Form class.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't Understand what you want but i hope this code solve your problem.

```
 public List<TextBox> GetTextbox(Form f)
    {
        List<TextBox> txtboxlist = new List<TextBox>();

        foreach (var Control in f.Controls)
        {
            if (Control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                txtboxlist.Add((TextBox)Control);
            }
        }

        return txtboxlist;
    }
```