# Linq to xml descendants

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

How can I get similar functionality to doc.Descendants() using linq against a collection of objects that contains sub collections of the same objects X levels deep?

The last nested collection contains the data in need to get at, all the other parent collections are merely groupings.  I could transform the collection to an XDocument and call the descendants function but I would prefer to mimic that functionality against this object collection.

```
public class ProductLine
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string ParentId  {get;set;}
  public string Name  {get;set;}
  public string Type  {get;set;}
  public string Level  {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<ProductLine> Children  {get;set;}
}
```

I can have a list of ProductLine that contains child lists of ProductLine.  The nested levels can vary depending on how the data was set up so I never know how many levels there are.  The bottom most list will have a Type="Model" while every list prior will have a Type="Series" resulting in something like:

```
Series1
   Series2
      Series3
          Model1
          Model1
   Series2
      Model3
      Model4
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/fe3d441d-1e49-4855-8ae8-60068b3ef741/

Answer (score 2):

With this [Node class](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2013/07/30/tree-node-nodes-descendants-ancestors.aspx), the solution is quite easy.

Change the ProductLineClass a litte bit:

```
public class ProductLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    // The level property is no longer needed because it is a property of the Node class
    public IEnumerable<ProductLine> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Create a tree:

```
var productlinesInAFlatList = GetListOfproductLines();

// Create alle the trees that can me made with the flad list based on Id and ParentId's
var rootNodes = Node<ProductLine>.CreateTree(productlinesInAFlatList, p => p.Id, p => p.ParentId);

// Assume there is only one tree in this flat ist
var rootNode = rootNodes.Single();
```

Get all info you need:

```
// Get the nodes that has no childnodes
var nodesWithoutChildNodes = rootNode.Descendants.Where(n => !n.Descendants.Any());

// If you just want the values of this childnodes
var values = nodesWithoutChildNodes.Values();

// When you need the levels of the values
var levels = nodesWithoutChildNodes.Select(n => n.Level);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq's [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) function.

```
IEnumerable<ProductLine> products = <something>;
IEnumerable<ProductLine> modelProducts = products
    .SelectMany((x) => x.Children)
```

However, this will only flatten to one depth. You need to look a Recursive SelectMany for the full effect. See the following links for more advice.

- [recursive list flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141467/recursive-list-flattening)
- [is it possible to implement a recursive selectmany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409194/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-recursive-selectmany)