# How can I flatten a collection of objects (which in turn contain collections)?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable collection, which is hierarchical in that one element contains several within it. Thus, if I do a count, I may get 7-8 as the return int, when really there could be 500 items (as they're nested).

How can I flatten this collection into a collection with all the elements and no nesting?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the following solution if your list contains loops: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141467/recursive-list-flattening/24747394#answer-24747394

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming that `smallEnumerable` is the collection with 7-8 items, each one of which has a property `SubItems` which is itself an enumerable of items of the same type, then you flatten like this:

```
var flattened = smallEnumerable.SelectMany(s => s.SubItems);
```

If each one of the `SubItems` can have `SubItems` itself, then some recursion is in order:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> RecursiveFlatten(IEnumerable<MyType> collection)
{
    return collection.SelectMany(
      s => s.SubItems.Any() ? s.Concat(RecursiveFlatten(s.SubItems)) : s);
}
```