# Remove selected Node in Hierarchy with recursion and generics

Tags: c#, list, recursion, hierarchy, flatten

I want to flatten a hierarchy of objects with an open Generic `T`.

This link [Recursive List Flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141467/recursive-list-flattening)

shows how to do that taking a passed IEnumerable. But I want to flatten a passed object T and

its property Children in a generic and recursively way.

```
U1.Children(U2,U3,U4)
U2.Children(U9,U10)
U3.Children(U11,U12)
U4.Children(U20,U30)
```

I pass to the method `U1`(selected node) and I want to get this flat list:

```
U1,U2,U3,U4,U9,U10,U11,U12,U20,U30
```

Is that possible somehow in a generic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a recursive extension method that accepts a function for retrieving children:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren)
{
    IEnumerable<T> rootSingleton = new T[] { root };
    IEnumerable<T> children = getChildren(root);
    IEnumerable<T> descendants = children.SelectMany(child => Flatten(child, getChildren));
    return rootSingleton.Concat(descendants);
}
```

Then, you could consume it like so:

```
var flat = u1.Flatten(u => u.Children);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your hierarcy is only one level depth you might use select many with union

```
public IEnumerable<T> Flattern<T>(IEnumerable<T> input) where T : ISomeinterface {
    return input.SelectMany(t=> t.Children).Union(input)
}
```

Well this code will not compile uness you'll constraint it with some base class or interface that has a `Children` property. The compiler must know that the object has that propertyl

Comment: nah... The input must not be a IEnumerable<T> but T with a Children Property. See my sample.