# Concat all strings inside a List<List<string>> using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My question is almost same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559415/concat-all-strings-inside-a-liststring-using-linq), but the List dimension is n.
How to concat all strings inside a **`List<List<List...<string>>`** (n dimension list) using LINQ ?

---

NOTE: Interested for both cases, **n** is **known** or **unknown**

Comment: using c# right? because the same question is tagged c#.

Comment: you should do this using reflection since the type of list is not known.

Comment: Use `.SelectMany` to flatten it, and then use the answer you found.

Comment: use [octavioccl`s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33837093/4767498). since it doesnt use reflection. its hundred times faster than my approach. so if i were you i would accept his answer instead ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the linked question is tagged as c# so i add this answer with c# code.

If the number of nested lists are known You have to use `SelectMany()` over and over to unwrap all the nested lists to sequence of chars. then make string out of that sequence.

```
List<List<List<string>>> nestedList = new List<List<List<string>>>();
var result = new string(nestedList.SelectMany(x => x).SelectMany(x => x).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray());
```

If the number of nested lists are not known you have to use reflection, since the type is not known. I didnt used reflection directly but actually dynamic type does. The performance would be terrible here of course ;) but it does what you want.

```
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;

//...

private static string ConcatAll<T>(T nestedList) where T : IList
{
    dynamic templist = nestedList;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            List<dynamic> inner = new List<dynamic>(templist).SelectMany<dynamic, dynamic>(x => x).ToList();
            templist = inner;
        }
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException)
    {
        List<object> l = templist;
        return l.Aggregate("", (a, b) => a + b);
    }
}
```

Here is the test

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<List<List<string>>> nestedList = new List<List<List<string>>>
    {
        new List<List<string>> {new List<string> {"Hello "}, new List<string> {"World "}},
        new List<List<string>> {new List<string> {"Goodbye "}, new List<string> {"World ", "End "}}
    };

    Console.WriteLine(ConcatAll(nestedList));
}
```

Outputs:

```
Hello World Goodbye World End
```

**Update:**

After a bit fiddling i ended up this implementation. maybe better without try catch.

```
private static string ConcatAll<T>(T nestedList) where T : IList
{
    dynamic templist = nestedList;
    while (templist.Count > 0 && !(templist[0] is char?))
    {
        List<dynamic> inner = new List<dynamic>(templist).SelectMany<dynamic, dynamic>(x =>
        {
            var s = x as string;
            if (s != null)
            {
                return s.Cast<dynamic>();
            }
            return x;
        }).ToList();
        templist = inner;
    }
    return new string(((List<object>) templist).Cast<char>().ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be using a recursive method to flatten all your lists:

```
 static IEnumerable<string> Flatten(IEnumerable enumerable)
 {
        foreach (object el in enumerable)
        {
            if (enumerable is IEnumerable<string>)
            {
                yield return (string) el;
            }
            else
            {
                IEnumerable candidate = el as IEnumerable;
                if (candidate != null)
                {
                    foreach (string nested in Flatten(candidate))
                    {
                        yield return nested;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

With this method you can concat all the strings this way:

```
 List<List<List<string>>> nestedList = new List<List<List<string>>>
                                       {
                                          new List<List<string>> {new List<string> {"Hello "}, new List<string> {"World "}},
                                          new List<List<string>> {new List<string> {"Goodbye "}, new List<string> {"World ", "End "}}
                                      };

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ",Flatten(nestedList)));
```

This idea was taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141467/recursive-list-flattening).

Comment: Great answer. I was about to post something similar, but couldn't get it to work correctly :-(. By the way, is that null check in `else` clause necessary? If it is, could you please explain why?