# C# LINQ SelectMany with Default

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, func

I am looking for an elegant solution to aggregate a child collection in a collection into one large collection. My issue is when certain child collections could be null.

EG:

```cs
var aggregatedChildCollection = parentCollection.SelectMany(x=> x.ChildCollection);
```

This throws an exception should any of the child collection objects be null. Some alternatives are:

```cs
// option 1
var aggregatedChildCollection = parentCollection
    .Where(x=>x.ChildCollection != null)
    .SelectMany(x => x.ChildCollection);

// option 2
var aggregatedChildCollection = parentCollection
    .SelectMany(x => x.ChildCollection ?? new TypeOfChildCollection[0]);
```

Both would work but I am doing a certain operation on quite a few child collections on the parent, and it is becoming a bit unweilding.

What I would like is to create an extension method that checks if the collection is null and if so does what option 2 does - adds an empty array. But my understanding of Func is not to a point where I know how to code this extension method. I do know that the syntax I would like is like this:

```cs
var aggregatedChildCollection = parentCollection.SelectManyIgnoringNull(x => x.ChildCollection);
```

Is there a simple extension method that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectManyIgnoringNull<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)
{
    return source.Select(selector)
        .Where(e => e != null)
        .SelectMany(e => e);
}
```

And use like this:

```
var aggregatedChildCollection = parentCollection
    .SelectManyIgnoringNull(x => x.ChildCollection);
```

Comment: A great solution - in my case I have combined it with Cory Nelson's answer that uses `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` instead of cutting out the null collections so that I will always have at the very least an empty collection.

Comment: That also works, but be mindful that Cory linked to code that has a licence attached, so you will need to provide attribution.

Answer (score 1):

If `ParentCollection` is your own class you should also be able to a default constructor to the class such as:

```
public ParentCollection{
    public ParentCollection() {
        ChildCollection = new List<ChildCollection>();
    }
}
```

That should prevent the null ref exception and give you an empty list if it doesn't have anything in it. At least this works with EF models.

Comment: No, unfortunately I cannot guarantee that any of the child collections will be populated. It's not that the class is invalid if a child collection is null, I just want to group all the child collections into one collection and ignore any nulls by treating them as an empty collection.

Answer (score 1):

Your "option 2" is what I would do, with a minor tweak: use `Enumerable.Empty()` instead of creating an empty array to reduce the amount of new objects you're creating.

I use a trivial extension method [`Touch()`](https://github.com/ctl-global/ctl-core/blob/master/Ctl.Core/Extensions/EnumerableExtensions.cs#L182) -- named after the *nix utility -- to keep the LINQ syntax flow and reduce typing:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Touch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) =>
    items ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
```

And would use it as:

```
var aggregatedChildCollection = parentCollection
    .SelectMany(x => x.ChildCollection.Touch());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the overhead from the LINQ extension by using the `SelectMany` [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ed448fa6fb6ff3a1)

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectManyNotNull<TSource, TResult>(
         this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector) 
{
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        var subElements = selector(element);
        if (subElements != null)
            foreach (TResult subElement in subElements )
                yield return subElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - a good resource and interesting to see how they do it.